# How to provoke a WerFault.exe

Tags: windows, crash, automated-tests

During our automated software tests we're also checking for crashes our application. If crashes occur, they're to my experience in either of the following categories:

1. the main application can detect and report the crash of a sub process (not of interest here)
2. the main application itself crashes, causing a WerFault.exe process
3. some other application run alongside crashes, also causing a WerFault.exe process

In order to stabilize our test systems for the categories 2 and 3, I want to write a simple crashing app:

**How could I provoke a WerFault.exe?**

(side note: we're testing on Windows 10, as well as some legacy Windows 7 systems)

Comment: Causing an application to crash is as simple as `*(int*)0 = 42;`. If you what to crash another process you're going to have to inject that code. There are many ways to inject code into a running process. Pick one.

Comment: @IInspectable - not need inject code. possible call `CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)` for example

Comment: @rbm Yes, that's one way to inject code.

Comment: possible call this and injecting code. and possible call this - [try] execute code in remote process, without injecting any code. but this is already game of words